# Unity Kick Player Car Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can  someone please tell me how to incorporate this
code 
into one below? 
I really don't know what I'm doing; it does not work and just freezes. I want it the player to leave  without freezing the game  on the one side.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnPlayerDisconnected(NetworkPlayer player) {
    Debug.Log("Clean up after player " + player);
    Network.RemoveRPCs(player);
    Network.DestroyPlayerObjects(player);
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class RG_Disconnect : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GameObject lobbyManager;
        lobbyManager = GameObject.Find ("LobbyManager");
        if (lobbyManager != null)
            Destroy(lobbyManager);
        NetworkManager.Shutdown ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Garage");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it freezes. You are loading the scene with name "Garage" in every frame update.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html
LoadScene is only meant to be used once to load a specific scene.